# Minor ticks in pandas plot

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

So I am trying to get minor tick grid lines to get displayed but they don't seem to appear on the plot. An example code is

```
data_temp = pd.read_csv(dir_readfile, dtype=float, delimiter='\t', 
                    names = names, usecols=[0,1,2,3,4])

result = data_temp.groupby(['A', 'D']).agg({'B':'mean', 'E':'mean'})
result2 = result.unstack()

x = np.arange(450, 700, 50, dtype = int)
plt.grid(True, which='both')
plt.minorticks_on()

result2.B.plot(lw=2,colormap='jet',marker='.',markersize=4, 
                  title='A v/s B', legend = True, grid = 'on' ,
                  xlim = [450, 700], ylim = [-70, -0], xticks = x)
```

What I get is

[image: Plot]

The major grid lines are displayed but the minor ones are not. I looked into the pandas documentation but just see the grid option. I was hoping to get the minor ticks grid lines to be a every 10th location on the X axis that is 460 470 etc and every location on the Y (actual scale of Y is a bit smaller)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before `plt.show()` add `plt.minorticks_on()`.

If you want to add minor ticks for selected axis then use:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='minor',bottom='off')
```

Comment: I see what you were saying but I don't understand if pandas does not have a minor ticks options how does it override my previous settings?